# How to sort a list of strings by frequency?

Tags: python, list, file, sorting, append

I have a list of files

```
example_list = [7.gif, 8.gif, 123.html]
```

There are over 700k elements and I need to sort them by frequency to see the most accessed file and least accessed file.

```
for i in resl:
    if resl.count(i) > 500:
        resl2.append(i)
print(resl2)
```

When I run this it never compiles. And i have tried other methods but no results.

Comment: This is to determine all files that occur more than 500 times. I just need to find out which file occurs the most.

Comment: It compiles, it's just very slow, because your algorithm takes quadratic time

Answer (score 3):

Your algorithm is unecessarily quadratic time. The following is linear

```
from collections import Counter
resl2 = [k for k,v in Counter(resl).items() if v > 500]
```

If you need them sorted, then do something like

```
resl2 = [(k,v) for k,v in Counter(resl).items() if v > 500]
resl2.sort(key=lambda kv: kv[1])
resl2 = [k for k,v in resl2]
```

Comment: so does this code sort as well by highest count? or just add them to the list in any order over 500 occurrences?

Comment: No, it doesn't sort by count, but you can obviously do that

Answer (score 1):

From [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60470789/how-to-sort-a-list-of-strings-by-frequency/60470930#comment106977382_60470834):

> I just need to find out which file occurs the most.

So:

`statistics.mode(example_list)`

Answer (score 0):

Note that `i` represents an element from the array and not an integer

```
for i in resl:
    if resl.count(i) > 500:
        resl2.append(i)
print(resl2)
```

Change it to this.

```
for i in range(0,len(resl)-1):
    if i > 500:
        resl2.append(resl[i])
print(resl2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this trick using a `set` ;)

Here you have a minimal example for a list of files and showing when it appears 2 times:

```
files = ['10.gif', '8.gif', '0.gif', '0.doc', '0.gif', '0.gif', '0.tmp', '0.doc', '0.gif']

file_set = set(files)
files_freq = [0]*len(file_set)

for n,file in enumerate(file_set):
    files_freq[n] = files.count(file)

sorted_list = [f for n,f in sorted(zip(files_freq, file_set), key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True) if n >= 2]
print(sorted_list)
```

and the output will be: `['0.gif', '0.doc']`

The `set` will filter the list only to unique occurrences of each file and the loop will calculate the count of each file.

After, the spooky list comprehension is the *trick*!

```
[f for n,f in sorted(zip(files_freq, file_set), key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True) if n >= 2]
```

This will create a list only with the files which appeared 2 or more times, then the `key` part forces the `sorted` function to use the first `files_freq` from `zip(files_freq, file_set)` to do the sorting and `reverse` is to sort the list in descendant order, showing the highest frequencies before.

Comment: this is *still quadratic time*